# Why does the Clojure reader get confused with keywords containing colons?

Tags: clojure, clojure-repl

From the [reader docs](http://clojure.org/reader):

> Keywords are like symbols, except:
>
> They can and must begin with a colon, e.g. :fred.
>
> They cannot contain '.' or name classes.
>
> A keyword that begins with two colons is resolved in the current namespace

and

> A symbol can contain one or more non-repeating ':'s.

So it looks like the docs should explicitly allow `:my:keyword` as a keyword.

This works in my REPL:

```
user=> {:my:keyword 1}
{:my:keyword 1}
```

and this works:

```
user=> {:mykeyword
  #_=> 1}
{:mykeyword 1}
```

and even this works

```
=> (clojure.edn/read-string (pr-str {:my:keyword 1}))
{:my:keyword 1}
```

But this doesn't:

```
user=> {
  #_=> :my:keyword

RuntimeException EOF while reading, starting at line 1
clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)
```

I can't put a newline in the middle of a hashmap literal immediately following a keyword containing a colon.

I can do this for other keywords. This works OK.

```
user=> {
  #_=> :one
  #_=> 1
  #_=> }
{:one 1}
```

Why? Is this just a quirk of the reader? AFAICT `:my:keyword` is a syntactically valid keyword. Should I be worried about other inconsistencies?

I'm using

```
REPL-y 0.3.5,
nREPL 0.2.6
Clojure 1.6.0
```

Comment: might help to know, what *your* repl there is.  works fine with e.g. `java -cp clojure-1.7.0-RC1.jar clojure.main`. i get the same error with a lein repl (1.6)

Answer (score 0):

As your last example stands, you haven't completed the map, so I would expect it to throw an exception with any value where `:my:keyword` is. This works for me.

```
{
 :my:keyword 1
 }
=> {:my:keyword 1}
```

Comment: My REPL doesn't meet your expectation, see most recent edit. Which version are you using?

Comment: Your example in the question doesn't close the map, can you check again with map } closed?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Do you mean the example I'm having trouble with? In this this example the exception is thrown before I can close the map, and that's my problem.